# kafka connect Transform base64decode a field

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using kafka RMQ source connector to fetch data from a RMQ queue. One of the field is base64encoded and it has a json structure. I'm using Extract transform to extract this field but I'm not sure how to decode this field, I tried to write my own smt to decode this field but I'm getting error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String` when I decode this field and try to put it into updatedvalue of the record because the message is a Json struct. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Below is my connector config.

```
{
    "name" : "RabbitMQ_Source",
    "connector.class" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "kafka.topic" : "RMQ_Topic",
    "rabbitmq.queue" : "rmqqueue",
    "rabbitmq.username":"username",
    "rabbitmq.virtual.host":"dummy",
    "rabbitmq.password":"password",
    "rabbitmq.host":"x.x.x.x",
    "rabbitmq.port":"5674",
    "transforms": "ExtractField",
    "transforms.ExtractField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
    "transforms.ExtractField.field":"body"
  }
```

Below is the message in the queue that I'm trying to consume, Body is the main the field that needs to be sent to Kafka topic after decoding. If I just use extract transform then it is working fine but I can only see encoded message in the kafka topic.

```
{
   "consumerTag": "abcd",
   "envelope": {
      "deliveryTag": 1,
      "isRedeliver": false,
      "exchange": "rmqqueue",
      "routingKey": "rmqqueue"
   },
   "basicProperties": {
      "contentType": "text/plain",
      "contentEncoding": null,
      "headers": {},
      "deliveryMode": 2,
      "priority": 0,
      "correlationId": null,
      "replyTo": null,
      "expiration": null,
      "messageId": null,
      "timestamp": null,
      "type": null,
      "userId": null,
      "appId": null
   },
   "body": "eyJXSFMiOlt7IkNoYXJhY3RlciBTZXQiOiJVVEYtOCIsImFjdGlvbiI6InJld3JpdGUiLCJVcGRhdGUtRGF0ZS1UaW1lIjoiMjAyMC0wMy0yNSAwOTowMDowMjoxOSJ9XX0="
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the the `ByteArrayConverter`

```
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"
```

There's an example of this [here](https://rmoff.net/2020/01/08/streaming-messages-from-rabbitmq-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect/).